# Upload Data from Local Database to Live Database in ASP.Net using SQL 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, remote-server

I am working on a web application which have two parts.

1) One is the online web site at online server.

2) The second is running on local machines/computers.

The structure of database is same on both live and on local. Now a user can make changes on the local database and then publish them on to the live server.

How can I update data from local database to online database? Which is the best technique to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Any of the Version Controller tool like TFS, It would help in check in your changes